# Analisando strings em um arquivo texto e retornando a string que mais apareceu

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso analisar strings em um arquivo texto e retornar a que mais aparece (se houver empate pegar as duas as duas) e salvar em outro arquivo texto.
Eu abro o arquivo e analiso as linhas mas não sei como verificar a que mais aparece.
Exemplo:

arquivo "A" - Entrada

1 #BrasilNaCopa

2 #OperacaoLavaJato

3 #PartiuAD2

4 #PartiuAD2

5 #OperacaoLavaJato

6 #PartiuAD2

7 #DietaSegundaFeira

Arquivo "B" - Saída

1 #PartiuAD2

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Primeiramente, visto que é um usuário novo, faça o [tour] para obter uma visão geral rápida do site. Após, entre em [edit] e adicione o código que você desenvolveu. Será mais fácil para nós indicar onde falhou do que recriar uma solução do zero. Obviamente que outras soluções equivalentes podem aparecer, mas saber onde errou é fundamental para aprender. Para adicionar o código, basta colá-lo no editor da pergunta, selecioná-lo e pressionar o atalho `Ctrl+K` para formatá-lo corretamente. Já adiciono que o tipo `list` do Python possui um método chamado `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tenho poucas informações sobre seu caso então vou considerar o seguinte:

1. O Arquivo "A" tem uma palavra por linha
2. Você precisa encontrar qual a palavra aparece mais vezes, mas não tem uma lista com as palavras possíveis, ou seja, você tem que contar as palavras que estiverem dentro do Arquivo "A" sejam elas quais forem

**Considerando que o Arquivo "A" tem esse conteúdo:**

```
BrasilNaCopa
OperacaoLavaJato
PartiuAD2
PartiuAD2
OperacaoLavaJato
PartiuAD2
DietaSegundaFeira
```

**O que vamos precisar fazer é o seguinte:**

```
# Abrimos o arquivo "arquivoa.txt" para leitura
arquivoA = open('arquivoa.txt', 'r') 

# Lemos o conteúdo do aquivo para a variável "texto"
# A variável "texto" é uma lista onde cada item é uma linha
texto = arquivoA.readlines()

# === OBSERVAÇÇÕES IMPORTANTES ===
# Dar um print na variável texto:
#   print(texto) 
#
# Resultaria em:
#   ['BrasilNaCopa\n', 'OperacaoLavaJato\n', 'PartiuAD2\n', 'PartiuAD2\n', 'OperacaoLavaJato\n', 'PartiuAD2\n', 'DietaSegundaFeira\n']
#
# Observe que há o "\n" (quebra de linha) no final de cada string, vamos ter 
# que limpar isso depois

# Criamos um dicionário para armazenar a contagem nas palavras
contagem = dict()

for linha in texto:
    # Limpamos aquela quebra de linha (\n) com o strip()
    palavra = linha.strip()

    if palavra not in contagem.keys():
        # Se a palavra ainda não existir na contagem, incluimos com o valor 1
        contagem[palavra] = 1
    else:
        # Se a palavra já existe na contagem a gente soma 1 no valor atual
        contagem[palavra] += 1

# Nesse ponto o dicionário "contagem" já tem a contagem de todas as palavras
# Dar um print em contagem:
#   print(contagem)
#
# Resultaria em:
#   {'DietaSegundaFeira': 1, 'PartiuAD2': 3, 'OperacaoLavaJato': 2, 'BrasilNaCopa': 1}

# Agora obtemos a palavra com maior contagem
palavraMaisRepetida = max(contagem)

# Dar um print em palavraMaisRepetida:
#   print(palavraMaisRepetida)
#
# Resultaria em:
#   'PartiuAD2'
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Veja que aqui eu só abordei o tratamento para os casos em que só uma palavra aparece no topo da contagem. Você disse que em caso de empate no topo você deve pegar todas as palavras que estiverem no topo da contagem.

Eu vou deixar esse tratamento para você concluir, acho que você já entendeu o espírito da coisa e agora está fácil.

Também é preciso ainda gravar esse resultado da contagem no **Arquivo "B"**

Comment: Legal que essa resposta foi últil pra você, se você puder da um voto positivo pra ela também. Não custa nada e ainda da uma forcinha na minha reputação. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

É simples :)
Mas é importante que as palavras de ambos arquivos estejam em listas separadas! (uma pra cada).
Ai tu fazes assim:

```
palavras = {}
for x in a:    # a e b sao as listas
contador = 1
for y in b:
    if x == y:
        contador +=1
palavras[x] = contador
```

Pronto! Dai tu vais ter um dicionário cuja chaves são as palavras, e os valores são a quantidade de vezes que tal palavra se repete.